# How to add console window in Win32 Project, Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, windows-console

I'm going to add console window in Win32 Project, Visual Studio 2010. 
OS : Windows XP (x64 bit)

I'm going to debug some library which is developed with console project. 
I add this one in to my Win32 project.

Is there any solution to add console window in to Win32 Project ?

Comment: tried it, but I didn't get proper posting. I know My question is ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this blog post](http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/console-window-win32-app/) (which I found by typing "add console to win32 project" into Google), you can accomplish this with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    AllocConsole();

    HANDLE handle_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_out, _O_TEXT);
    FILE* hf_out = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
    setvbuf(hf_out, NULL, _IONBF, 1);
    *stdout = *hf_out;

    HANDLE handle_in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_in, _O_TEXT);
    FILE* hf_in = _fdopen(hCrt, "r");
    setvbuf(hf_in, NULL, _IONBF, 128);
    *stdin = *hf_in;

    // use the console just like a normal one - printf(), getchar(), ...
}
```